# A:Set text line-space by my method, when the characters length is 14-15 , it will show only one line

Tags: ios, uilabel

My label `mainTitle` to set line space:

```
[Util setLabelLineSpace:22 forLabel:((NoticeAnnouncementCell*)cell).mainTitle andStr:((InformationModel *)self.dataSource[indexPath.row]).title];
```

The Util method:

```
+ (void)setLabelLineSpace:(float)spacing forLabel:(UILabel *)label andStr:(NSString *)originStr{

    
    //label.numberOfLines = 0;
    if (originStr == nil) {
        originStr = @"";
    }
    NSString* string = originStr;
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style  = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    style.minimumLineHeight = spacing;
    style.maximumLineHeight = spacing;
    NSDictionary *attributtes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style};
    label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                             attributes:attributtes];
    [label sizeToFit];
}
```

The `string` should be `hi`, but use my Util method set line space, it shows `hi` with one line, should be `hi` with 2 line.  if the `string` add some character to make length longer , it will be two line,and no issue like first cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Line Breaks option in the attributes Inspector to 'character wrap'? 
[image]